# How to keep forking a process until I "almost" run out of memory

Tags: c, fork

I want to keep forking a process until I'm almost out memory. How Do I know how many times I can fork a process without crashing?

Comment: You don't and you can't, because it depends on how much memory everything else on the system is using, which can change at any moment.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Forking doesn't use much memory, because most operating systems use copy-on-write. So until one of the processes modifies some of the memory, the total memory used doesn't increase. It will probably just be the stack frame of the loop that changes.

Comment: It's an exercise from school, all it says was: fork until you can't. The teacher is not very helpful. He just said no fork bomb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is program to calculate estimate (using Linux API's):

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long maxmem() {
    struct sysinfo info;
    if (sysinfo(&info) < 0)
        return 0;
    return info.freeram;
}

long getmem(void) {
    struct rusage r_usage;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF,&r_usage);
    return r_usage.ru_maxrss;
}

int main() {
    printf("Can fork %d times. Mfm: %d, upp: %d\n", maxmem() / 1024 / getmem(), maxmem() / 1024, getmem());
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that this is just an estimate, you may need to run this code inside your application when it reaches peak memory usage.